# When NGINX is running why doesn't grep detect that it is listening on port 80?

Tags: linux, networking, grep, nginx

**Software**

CentOS 7.4.1708

Nginx 1.12.2

I thought that grep might be able to return all processes listening on port 80.  However I must be doing something wrong because Nginx didn't show up.

To confirm that Nginx was running:

```
$ service nginx status
Active: active (running)
```

But:

```
$ ps -ef | grep 80
root     280   2      0 09:50 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u4:3]first    11288 10899  0 17:41 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 80`
```

Shouldn't it return a reference to Nginx?  I'm trying to understand the basic mechanics but I'm sure I'm missing something.  Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Just to be clear: you know that grep doesn't _detect_ things, right? It's just _filtering_ the output of the previous command.

Comment: @mattdm actually no I didn't realize that.  I'm still pretty new at this.  Thanks!

Comment: In that case, welcome to Linux. :) I'd recommend picking up a book like Mark Sobell's [A Practical Guide to Linux Commands, Editors, and Shell Programming](http://www.sobell.com/CR3/index.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've confused `ps` for a different command. `ps` shows processes. You want either `lsof`:

```
lsof -i:80
```

Which may (as an example) show:

```
apache2  489     root    4u  IPv6  13547      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5441 www-data    4u  IPv6  13547      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 5442 www-data    4u  IPv6  13547      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

where pids 489, 5441, and 5442 are listening on port 80 (HTTTP),

or `ss`:

```
ss -lntp 'sport = :80'
State       Recv-Q Send-Q                  Local Address:Port                                   Peer Address:Port
LISTEN      0      128                                :::http                                             :::*                     users:(("apache2",pid=5442,fd=4),("apache2",pid=5441,fd=4),("apache2",pid=489,fd=4))
```

If you have the nginx process id, you can pass that directly to lsof to see what it has open, for example:

```
lsof -p 489 | grep TCP
apache2 489 root    3u  sock    0,8      0t0 13546 protocol: TCP
apache2 489 root    4u  IPv6  13547      0t0   TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

Comment: … or `netstat`.